# sqlite cursor.close takes too much time

Tags: android, sqlite

My code have some sqlite operators. I execute a sql, it has **500 rows**. Executing and getting rows take quite low time, but when I call `cursor.close()` function, it takes **10 seconds**.

How can I reduce this time consume ?

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
     String str1 = cursor.getString(0);
     String str2 = cursor.getString(1);
     System.out.println(str1+" and "+str2);
}
cursor.close();  // this line takes 13 seconds. but above code takes only 200 ms
```

code is something like this

Comment: instead of closing cursor have you tried closing database object??

Comment: no, I dont try. but, I need database object for next queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have suggest you to use method `startManagingCursor(Cursor c)` of Activity Class. Lets Activity handle Cursor for you as per Activity Life Cycle..

Form Docs [StartManagingCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29)...

```
public void startManagingCursor (Cursor c)
Since: API Level 1
```

**This method is deprecated.**
Use the new CursorLoader class with LoaderManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

This method allows the activity to take care of managing the given Cursor's lifecycle for you based on the activity's lifecycle. That is, when the activity is stopped it will automatically call deactivate() on the given Cursor, and when it is later restarted it will call requery() for you. When the activity is destroyed, all managed Cursors will be closed automatically.

If you are targeting **HONEYCOMB** or later, consider instead using `LoaderManager` instead, available via `getLoaderManager()`.